# Flash plugin failed to load (Opera, Linux)

Tags: linux, installation, plugins, opera, flash-player

So I installed new linux distro recently (pinguyOS) and now I am trying to install flash plugin for Opera browser: `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`.

The output of `dpkg --status flashplugin-installer` is:

```
The Adobe Flash Player plugin will work with a range of web-browsers including, limited to:
* Firefox
* Chromium
* SeaMonkey
* Iceweasel
* Iceape
* Galeon
* Epiphany
* Konqueror
```

Since Opera isn't listed I followed official instructions for installing Opera Adobe Flash Plugin:

http://www.opera.com/docs/linux/plugins/install/

I copied `libflashplayer.so` from its original directory to `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/opera/lib`. Flash player is still unable to load and when I check browser for installed plugins `opera://plugins` it says Flash Player is enabled but there is this weird version of the plugin:

[image: workspace]

I use Opera v 39.0 and the official opera documentation is outdated (v11.0) but I even tried to install PPAPI version of flash plugin and replace `libflashplayer.so` with `libpepflashplayer.so` but plugin is still not working. It shows still the same error: Flash plugin failed to load.

Can you help me find out where the problem is please?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, until I found the [doc on their official page](http://www.opera.com/docs/linux/plugins/install/#flash). Basically you have to do the following:

- `locate libflashplayer.so`, or
- `find / -name libflashplayer.so 2> /dev/null`

If Adobe Flash Player is not installed, or you wish to upgrade, proceed as follows:

- Download the plug-in from Adobe's website. The plug-in is available in various formats, including .deb, .rpm, and .tar.
- Follow the instructions on the download page.

  - If you choose the .tar file, you need to unpack it `tar xvf install_flash_player_10_linux.tar.gz`
  - copy libflashplayer.so to /usr/lib/opera/plugins
  - A user without root access can copy the the plug-in to `$HOME/.local/lib/opera/plugins`.
- Restart Opera.
- Verify that the plug-in is working by going to [Adobe's test page](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/).

Answer (score 0):

I can fix it first step for step and try if your browser show the video multimedia:

1º update or install chronium ffmpeg codec

```
sudo apt install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
```

2º if the bug persist:

try it: `sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin`

3º try installing this global codec for linux

here install ffmpeg version 4.x for linux

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu-18-04/

remember, every step when you change in your system try to play